# tf hub.module can't load elmo. I hope it works normally

Tags: elmo

When I run the following code with Jupyter Notebook, it originally worked normally, but suddenly an error pops up.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

tf.disable_eager_execution()
  
# Load pre trained ELMo model
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/1", trainable=True)
```

The error code is

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 149: invalid start byte

I had the same error before, so when I changed the version of Elmo, the problem was solved, but now it doesn't solve it either.